# How to create a org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody when using Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-io, multipartentity

So I'm trying to make a multipart-form POST and I want to attach a `org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody` to the `MultipartEntity` that I'm going to be posting. Now I've got the raw string file data that I want to populate the `FileBody` with already. However, this project is using Google App Engine which prohibits every way I've seen of generating the FileBody. Anyone know how to create a `FileBody` object and populate it in GAE?

Comment: Which ways have you seen it prohibit, and with which errors/warnings?

Comment: It restricts you from using classes that can write to files, like FileWriter and FileOutputStream. You need to make a java.io.File object in order to make a FileBody object

Comment: Basically it won't let you write to the user's local machine. I'm wondering if there's a way to create and populate a java.io.File object without writing to the user's local machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just ignore FileBody.  You want to use the method MultipartEntity.addPart(ContentBody content).  This works with FileBody, because FileBody's parent class implements ContentBody.

ContentBody is a super simple interface with just two methods.  Create a class that implements it, create an instance of your class, and pass it in to the addPart method.

```
public ByteContentBody implements ContentBody {
  private String name;
  private byte[] data;

  public ByteContentBody(String name, byte[] data) {
    this.name = name;
    this.data = data;
  }

  public String getFilename(){
    returns name;
  }

  public void writeTo(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    out.write(data);
  }
}
```

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.html

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/ContentBody.html

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up using, but with the apache HttpClient and HttpPost object to facilitate the post as well